# java.util.Properties multiple values ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, exception, properties

I have a property file which stores the name of a server and the port. These values are going to be used in an `Enum`, in order to be able to change the values without touching the code.

The content of the property looks like this:

```
PROD=FTPROD01:1122
```

The thing is i have to split the server and the port number, since i'm using these values as parameters for a method:

```
server = properties.getProperty(this.name(), "").split(":")[0];
try {
port = Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty(this.name(), "").split(":")[1]);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
System.err.println("error");
}
```

As you can see, im catching the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which is a runtime exception, in order to detect if the second value is missing, since the programm would crash in case the property file is "corrupt".

Is this a good way to do get multiple values, or are there any other approaches, which are more elegant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a good way to do get multiple values, or are there any other approaches, which are more elegant?

Sure - don't *try* to access the array for an invalid length - detect it before you do anything else.

```
String[] bits = properties.getProperty(this.name(), "").split(":");
if (bits.length == 2) {
  server = bits[0];
  port = Integer.valueOf(bits[1]); 
} else {
  // Log the corruption or whatever...
}
```

Note that this can still fail, if `valueOf` throws a `NumberFormatException`.

Basically you should avoid catch exceptions you can avoid provoking to start with.

Answer (score 3):

**Rule of thumb: Don't use Exceptions for normal flow.**

You can use array `length` to find if `port` is present, as follows:

```
String[] arr = String.valueOf(properties.getProperty(this.name(), "").split(":");

server = arr[0];
if(arr.length > 1)
{
    port = Integer.valueOf(arr[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if it works for you it's a good option :-)

Still, what will you do when somebody gives you a property-file that looks like:

```
PROD=
```

Hint: Expand the try/catch and perhaps prepare a default for when PROD is missing :-)

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can place a check before this to ensure property values

`if(properties.getProperty(this.name(), "").split(":").length > 1)`
Through this way , You can remove your exception handling code :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply have property like

```
PROD.SERVER=FTPROD01
PROD.PORT=1122
```

Property is mainly meant for key and a value.